# Filter the title to only affect the_title() template function

Tags: filters, hooks, get-the-title

I am using [the_title filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_title/) to add an HTML snippet under the title, as follows:

[image]

I only want the output to happen for the main title in the posts or page view.

That's why I added an early return to make sure that the filter only applies if [is_singular()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_singular/) returns `true`:

```
if ( ! is_singular() ) { return; }
```

But there is an issue, since the title may be loaded in other places inside the single view template.

For example, the [twentytwentyone theme](https://github.com/WordPress/twentytwentyone/blob/trunk/template-parts/content/content-page.php) displays the post or page edit link as follows:

```
edit_post_link(
sprintf(
     esc_html__( 'Edit %s', 'twentytwentyone' ),
     '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . get_the_title() . '</span>'
),
'<span class="edit-link">',
'</span>'
);
```

So I am having trouble with the HTML being output in places that I don't want.

How do you suggest to handle this situation (without touching the theme files) to make sure the snippet is only added under the main title area?

Comment: Which theme are you using ?

Comment: @GautamGolakiya This is a plugin oriented solution, so all WP Themes following current standards should work

Comment: The most reliable way would be to use custom hooks in the theme files, e.g. `do_action( 'before_main_title' ); the_title(); do_action( 'after_main_title' );`.. So you'd hook on the "after" action instead of `the_title`.

Comment: @SallyCJ Thanks, yes, this seems to be the cleanest approach. In this case, though, I am required to not touch the theme, it should work on "all" themes via a Plugin.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but I don't think that's possible because as you already know it, `the_title` (i.e. the hook) might be fired in various places in the single template and remember there are also template parts.